# How to say "I vaunt a broad knowledge of the subject" without bragging?

Tags: word-choice, terminology, formality, business-language

How can I say

> "I **vaunt** a broad knowledge and understanding of the subject"

without sounding too arrogant?

The verb `to vaunt` implies bragging, in my humble opinion.

Comment: The verb does imply bragging, so does using a very rarely used verb, I think (no really, thanks for making me look up that one ;) ). Then again, saying of yourself you have a broad knowledge and understanding of something might be seen as bragging as well, whether you vaunt it, state it or imply it.

Comment: thanks for your comment @oerkelens. In your expert opinion, what's a less bragging (and more kind) way of communicating my sentence? :)

Comment: How about just "I possess extensive knowledge and a strong understanding of the subject"? Or even just "have" if you want to be direct.

Comment: **SME** - *Subject Matter Expert*; also *vaunt* might be misunderstood (if spoken) as *want*.

Comment: @JessStone : In my expert opinion ( :X ) I think Jon Hanna's answer is quite good :)

Comment: I thought `vaunt`ing is what Count Dracula does: "I vaunt to suck your blood."

Answer (score 9):

*Vaunt* doesn't imply boasting, but states it outright ("to boast, to brag, to use vainglorious language").

The simple "I have a broad knowledge and understanding of the subject" should suffice. The main thing that will make it not seem boastful is the grounds you have for making the claim.

Ironically, "We are able to boast of a broad knowledge…" can sound less arrogant even though it claims to be boasting, because it suggests a degree of self-awareness. It would though IMO be more boastful in the singular than the plural (because if you are boasting as part of a team, then that can suggest your pride in your colleagues rather than personal arrogance), and as such I'd be more cautious of using it with *I* than with *we*.

Perhaps most modest, is to focus on the process:

> My experience with the R&D development of MadeUpCo and our work with other industry leaders through MadeUpIndustryBody has given me a broad knowledge and understanding of the subject.

It shows that your claim comes from more than just wishful thinking.

Comment: Thank you @Jon, appreciated. you can now brag about your answer!

Comment: NP. Incidentally the `inline computer code` format change you sugggested is for inline computer code.